# Referring to a concept in a not-imported ontology

Tags: owl, protege

I want to refer to concepts defined in other ontologies, using only the respective concepts URI, **without importing the outer ontology**. I think that this is compatible with OWL semantics, using `owl:equivalentTo` property.

Can somebody confirm that this is correct? Furthermore, could someone provide me with an example on how to do it (preferably using Protege)?

Comment: Without importing the other ontology, your inferences will be different, because you won't have the definitions the other ontology provides. If your goal is to have the same inferences with and without imports, it cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there is an ontology `anOnt:` in which there is a term `anOnt:Term` that you want to reuse in your ontology `yourOnt:`. You may import `anOnt:` and you're done. However, you can also redeclare the term `anOnt:Term` in your ontology, like this:

```
yourOnt:  a  owl:Ontology .
anOnt:Term  a  owl:Class .
# use anOnt:Term as you wish
```

But these options are only necessary if you want to comply with OWL 2 DL. OWL also defines OWL Full, and its [RDF-based semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/), where terms do not have to be declared at all. So you can just write:

```
yourOnt:SomeTerm  rdfs:subClass  anOnt:Term .
```

and that's compatible with OWL semantics, in the sense of the OWL 2 RDF-based semantics.

For more on whether you should use `owl:imports` or redeclare terms, or just reuse terms, you can read an [answer I wrote on `answers.semanticweb.com`](http://www.emse.fr/~zimmermann/QA/q2.html) (a now deceased website). For more on why OWL 2 has two semantics, you can read [another answer I wrote on `answers.semanticweb.com`](http://www.emse.fr/~zimmermann/QA/q.html).

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can refer to concepts in an external ontology is by importing it. After you have imported it you can use `owl:equivalentTo` to assert that say the `Identity` concept in your ontology is equivalent to the `external:ID` concept of the external ontology.

Comment: In fact, the answer is more complicated than this. You're narrowing down the question to conformance wrt the OWL 2 DL syntax and OWL 2 Direct Semantics. There is much more you can do without conforming to those specs (while still being compatible in some sense).

Comment: @Henriette: Thank you for your answer. It is not what I would like to hear but still I highly appreciate your time.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann: What do you mean? Can you give an example? How would I be compatible with OWL if I did not follow the OWL semantics?