# Legal to just take an IRI instead of importing an ontology?

Tags: import, mapping, owl, ontology

If I want to use some concepts from other ontologies, but I do not want to import them, because I just need few concepts but get thousands of axioms which makes the ontology confusing and increase its size significantly.
Is it good modeling practice to just take the IRIs of the concept?
The concept is defined and if necessary, one can import the ontology later, without doing a mapping, since the IRIs are correct. For me, it sounds as a great option, but I could not find it somewhere. Is there a snag?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Referring to a concept in a not-imported ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47695745/1260887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need at least a declaration for the iris you wish to use, since otherwise your ontology will have missing declarations (i.e., you have to assert if the iri is a class, a data property, etc.).

Legally, if the iris are in a publicly accessible ontology, I can't think of any snag - I'm not aware of any licence that would allow you to import and use the ontology but not declare and use the iris it contains. It wouldn't be good practice to define the iris in a way that's incompatible with the original ontology - that's likely to create confusion.

Comment: Thanks you Ignazio, that answers my question!